# "That hints at the most unpredictable force disguised despots contend with: their citizens."

Tags: sentence-meaning

could someone help parse out this sentence?
"That hints at the most unpredictable force disguised despots contend with: their citizens." -- from The Economist

After several attempts, I still find it very puzzling!

Comment: can you tell us what your attempt was?    Do you know what a despot is, and what a ised despot might be?  What does "contend" mean

Answer (score 2):

That - refers to a previous statement or sentence

Hints at - implies, points to, refers to or otherwise relates to

The most unpredictable force disguised despots contend with - maybe easier to understand if you put 'that' between force and disguised. Disguised despots contend with multiple issues (force used to mean something that influences them) and this is the most unpredictable

": Their ctizens" the citizens of the despots is the most unpredictable force mentioned previously in the sentence

Let me know if that helps